# Azure Active Directory - Setting Token Expiry in java

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, ucwa

I'm new to azure and I'm trying to set expiry time for my access token, in java, but im not able to find any examples to do how to set it. Please help how to set the expiry time, from 60 minutes to 1 day.

I want to increase the  "expires_in": "3600", to atleast 8 hours or more than it.

In the code, here I'm not able to get any methods like set param or set headers. Please help me how i can .

Here is the link for params:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#cmdlet-reference

Thank you.

```
AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {

              String refreshToken = request.getParameter("refreshToken");
              String currentUri   = request.getRequestURL().toString();  

            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant + "/", true,
                    service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context
                    .acquireTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken,
                            new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null,
                            null);

            result = future.get();

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // token values I'm getting

{
 "access_token": "<requested-access-token>",
 "token_type": "<token-type-value>",
 "expires_in": "3600",

"expires_on": "<access-token-expiration-date-time>",
 "resource": "<app-id-uri>",
 "refresh_token": "<oauth2-refresh-token>",
 "scope": "user_impersonation",

 "id_token": "<unsigned-JSON-web-token>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Powershell script to create the policy. Here is the script for your reference.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -Force

Connect-AzureAD -confirm

$policy=New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"08:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "tonytestpolicy" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

If you must do this in your java code, you can use graph api.(The powershell script also calls this api). Here is the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-post?view=graph-rest-beta).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "displayName":"CustomTokenLifetimePolicy",
  "definition":["{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"8:00:00\"}}"],
  "type":"TokenLifetimePolicy"
}
```

Comment: I followed ur post request with access token generated, I'm getting {
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b29a2d28-41a3-4db0-81fb-394e66df74dc",
            "date": "2019-07-10T05:36:01"
        }
    }
} while updating with bearer token, tried to update this.. can u please guide me.. thankyou ju.

Comment: @curious_one Have you granted Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission?

Comment: @curious_one I find your code is using client credential flow which doesn't support this api. See the permission needed to call the api here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-update?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions

Comment: @curious_one Do you have to do this in your code? You can use powershell or graph explorer to do this. Here is the graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: I apologize for not replying, i have been given some different task now, so i did not check this. So i will check after some time. if it works, i will definitely mark this as answer without delay. Thank you ju for ur valuable help.

Comment: Hi.. i have done what you have said, i have successfully put 24 hour expiry in graph policies url, like what you have said. But, new access tokens generated, for new resources after that, are still having only 3600 seconds expiry.  How to make the token expiry setting applicable for next access tokens generated ?

Comment: @curious_one Have you assigned the policy to the app? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-assign?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: I am generating a access token using this url, https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token, through post requests, how to assign a policy of a app to this request

Comment: @curious_one To use this url, you will need the parameters, such as client_id(this is the application id)

Comment: I am able to set up expiry time, but they are not applicable to subsequent generation of access tokens. Anyways thanks for your help.