# An event has occurred in which the token expires in the application that accesses the Graph API

Tags: java, graph, azure-active-directory

An event has occurred in which the token expires in the application that accesses the Graph API.

Increase the token expiration date from the default 60 minutes,
I'm looking for Java source code to update the token when it expires.

I found a link to the sample code in the post below, but the link was broken.

Increase the token expiration date from the default 60 minutes,
Is there some Java sample code that updates the token when it expires?

[Azure Active Directory - Setting Token Expiry in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957363/azure-active-directory-setting-token-expiry-in-java)

Comment: Hi @TA Hyouno, does my reply help? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Create tokenLifetimePolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tokenlifetimepolicy-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
  "definition": [
    "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"8:00:00\"}}"
  ],
  "displayName": "CustomTokenLifetimePolicy",
  "isOrganizationDefault": true
}
```

**In java:**

Note: add required application permission first.

[image]

```
// ClientSecretCredential needs application permission with client credential flow.
final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
        .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
        .tenantId(TENANT_GUID)
        .build();

final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(SCOPES, clientSecretCredential);

final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();

TokenLifetimePolicy tokenLifetimePolicy = new TokenLifetimePolicy();
LinkedList<String> definitionList = new LinkedList<String>();
definitionList.add("definition-value");
tokenLifetimePolicy.definition = definitionList;
tokenLifetimePolicy.displayName = "displayName-value";
tokenLifetimePolicy.isOrganizationDefault = true;

graphClient.policies().tokenLifetimePolicies()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(tokenLifetimePolicy);
```